# git: different versions give different GIT STATUS

Tags: git, git-bash, msys2

I'm using two shells on Windows: **MSYS2** and **GitBash**

In **GitBash**, `git status` says *everything is clean, up to date* while **MSYS2** `git status` shows dozens of files as **modified**

**GitBash**

```
$ git --version
git version 2.35.1.windows.2
```

**MSYS2**

```
$ git --version
git version 2.36.1
```

Comment: Different line ending settings, perhaps? Compare the output of `git config --list --show-origin` between the two.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat which field do I look at?

Comment: Something about "crlf", I believe. Or just check all of them.

Comment: Here is a more targeted command: run `git config --get core.autocrlf` in both shells. If the answer is different, that's your explanation. I prefer `input` for that setting, by the way, but that's me.  `git diff` in the one showing differences should also explain what Git thinkgs is different.